# mysql how to enable concurrent insert

Tags: mysql, concurrency, insert

I have a MySQL database where everyday I make a new table and I end-up with around 5M rows in the day end. My problem is during the peak hour our reporting gets real slow. We are trying to figure out the cause of the issue. One reason can be, the select queries can not execute properly as our system keeps inserting frequently during the peak hour. From MySQL website I came to know that concurrent insert can be a solution of this problem.

Therefore, how can I enable concurrent inserts in my system and check if it is working? And what issues I may face if I use it?

I am using MySQL server 5.0.95

Answer (score 0):

To enable concurrent insert, add "concurrent_insert=2" as server system variables.